# How to transpose a PyArrow.Table object in Python using PyArrow structures only (preferably maintaining contiguous memory ordering)?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, transpose, pyarrow

I wonder if there's a way to transpose PyArrow tables without e.g. converting them to pandas dataframes or python objects in between.

Right now I'm using something similar to the following example, which I don't think is very efficient (I left out the schema for conciseness):

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa

np.random.seed(1234)  # For reproducibility

N, M = 3, 4

arrays = [pa.array(np.random.randint(0, 4, N)) for _ in range(M)]
names = [str(x) for x in range(M)]
table = pa.Table.from_arrays(arrays, names)

print("Original:\n", table.to_pandas().values)

transposed = table.from_pandas(table.to_pandas().T)

print("\nTransposed:\n", transposed.to_pandas().values)
```

Resulting nicely in:

```
Original:
 [[3 1 0 1]
 [3 0 1 3]
 [2 0 3 1]]

Transposed:
 [[3 3 2]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 1 3]
 [1 3 1]]
```

In the program I'm working on currently, I'm using PyArrow to prevent what seems to be a memory leaking issue I encountered using pandas dataframes, of which I couldn't pin down the exact source/cause beyond the use of dataframes being the origin.

Hence, besides efficiency reasons, not wanting to use pandas objects here was the reason to use PyArrow data structures in the first place.

Is there a more direct way to do this?

If so, would the transposed result have contiguous memory blocks if the original table is also contiguous?

Also, would calling `transposed.combine_chuncks()` reorder memory for this table to be contiguous along the columnar axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more direct way to do this?

No.  It's not possible today.  You're welcome to file a JIRA ticket.  I couldn't find one.

The C++ API has array builders which would make this pretty straightforward but there is no python support for these at the moment (there is a JIRA for that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3917 but the marshaling overhead would probably become a bottleneck even if that was available).

> If so, would the transposed result have contiguous memory blocks if the original table is also contiguous?

> Also, would calling transposed.combine_chuncks() reorder memory for this table to be contiguous along the columnar axis?

Arrow arrays are always contiguous along the columnar axis.  Are you asking if the entire table would be represented as one contiguous memory region?  In that case the answer is no.  Arrow does not try and represent entire tables as a single contiguous range.

Comment: Thank you. I might file a ticket later on, although I suppose this is one of these things that will probably be implemented anyway after more important stuff has been taken care of.

About the contiguous memory question; I thought that transposing could perhaps result in the 0th new column pointing to the 0th entry in each of the old columns, etc., leading to awkward memory arrangements. This idea probably doesn't make much sense though; I'm a newbie w.r.t anything remotely resembling low-level stuff. I should read up some of [this](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html) again.

Answer (score 2):

Arrow being a columnar format, it doesn't lend itself well to this king of workload (tables with uniform types that are more like tensor/matrices).

The same could be said to pandas (to a lesser extent), and numpy is better suited for this type of payload. So instead of converting to pandas and transposing, you could convert to numpy and transpose.

It requires a bit more code, because the conversion from arrow to numpy only works at array/column level (not at table level). See the [doc](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/numpy.html)

```
transposed_matrix = np.array([col.to_numpy() for col in table]).T
transposed_arrays = [pa.array(col) for col in transposed_matrix]
transposed_names = [str(x) for x in range(len(transposed_arrays))]
transposed_table = table.from_arrays(transposed_arrays, names=transposed_names)
```

Comment: I followed your advice. After having rewritten my program such that the extra information provided by pandas dataframes (index, column names, etc.) are encoded in a different way, using plain numpy arrays instead of dataframes solved the memory leak issue as well as giving significant performance boost.